# Hide "unwanted" methods from libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, libraries

I use eclipse and in some of my heavily used libraries (lets stick to slf4j in this example) there is a large amount of methods I will NEVER use.

Its up to the point that if I use those methods its most likely a bug.
(or a bad practice, missing debug info (checkNotNull(Object)), or dangerous to use)

For example there are 10 methods for "debug" alone. I need 3-4 at best.
How can I hide those other 5x 6-7 methods that clogs my code completion?

I know there is a feature in eclipse that hides classes and packages, however I haven't found such a feature for methods yet.

As an alternative I thought about using a "lite" library jar that only provides the methods I need and replace it with the original during the packaging. (I would use maven for this: lite = compile + optional/provided ; original = runtime scope)

However this alternative is tedious to maintain and may cause binary or license incompatibilities.

How can I hide "unwanted" methods from libraries in eclipse.

Comment: One option is to extend the class and deprecate methods you don't want used. Another is to create a wrapper that only exposes select methods.

Comment: How can you be sure that just because you are no using these methods today, you will not want to use them tomorrow ? Have you tried to use [Code Recommenders](https://eclipse.org/recommenders/) for completion ?

Comment: Code Recommenders is a good option, it will list the methods in the order they're most often used by developers.

Comment: @shmosel Extending the interfaces is not an option, because the implementations would no longer satisfy the interface. Deprecation alone is not an option, since I cannot alter that libraries. Using a wrapper would probably annoy/confuse other developers.

Comment: I said to extend the [implementation] class, not the interface. Of course, it isn't always possible; it's just a suggestion.

Comment: @FlorentBayle Thats one of the reasons why I would like to hide them instead of removing them or blocking their usage using wrappers. I use code recommenders, but it sometimes stiff suggests the wrong method or has no recommendations for private/commercial libraries. I will check for an option to fine tune the code recommenders.